# setting host env variable based on platform in skaffold.yml

Tags: kubernetes-helm, skaffold

I am new to skaffold, currently i try to find a way (may be it's not possible) to set host env variable based on platform, linux and mac os works with HOST but windows does not support this env variable. Is there any possibility to check platform then setValues inside skaffold.yml during helm install (we can set it with flag but the question is to supply variable which support all platforms)

currently it look like this in my skaffold.yml file

```
deploy:
  kubeContext: docker-desktop
  helm:
    releases:
     setValueTemplates:
      HOST: "{{.HOST}}"
```

the above stuff is not working for windows os which sets no value, how we can do this without set this manually in windows environment variables (edit system environment variables, i can able to set HOST variable inside my machine but i have to do this manually).

is there any possibility to write a function and return value based on platform to skaffold.yml?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the `setValueTemplates` allows you to use Go templates to compute the value to be set.  Go templates support [*actions*](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions), including if/else actions, so you should be able to use something like:

```
setValueTemplates:
  HOST: "{{if .HOST}}{{.HOST}}{{else}}notset{{end}}"
```